# Rebuild eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, editor

I have an eclipse plugin that ships with an editor.
I added a preference to change the color of the syntax highlighting but these changes only apply after I restart the editor manually.

I implemented syntax highlighting via an `DefaultDamagerRepairer` that gets a Scanner returning a token and in that token I define the respective color. I change the returning token via a `PropertyChangeListener` applied to the respective preference but as mentioned before the editor does not display the new color until I restart it.

Is there a way to rebuild or redraw the editor programatically?
I have found out that it will update the new colors partly if I start typing in the editor. I assume that this is because of the `PresentationReconciler` I have set up but I didn't find a way to force this reconciler to recompute the editor's content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `invalidateTextPresentation` method of your `ITextViewer` / `ISourceViewer` to get it to rebuild the whole screen using the new settings.